# If checkboxed is checked, textbox will compute

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

As shown in the image below, I have the `Sell Price` textbox and `Use Sell Price Percentage` textbox. My `Use Sell Price Percentage` have this code

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sellpCheck" id="scheck" onclick="document.getElementById('sell_price').disabled=this.checked;">
  * Use Sell Price Percentage
</label>
```

and here's my `Sell Price` textbox

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="sell_price" id="sell_price" step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' required>
```

lastly, my `Buy Price` textbox

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="buy_price" placeholder="Buying Price Per Unit" 
       step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' min="0" max="9999" required id="buyp">
```

Here's my initial jQuery code:

```
var buyp = parseInt($('#buyp').val());
var sellp = parseFloat($('#sellp').val());
$('#sell_price').val((buyp * ((sellp/100)+1)).toFixed(2))
```

What I want to happen, is when I click the `Use Sell Price Percentage` the `Sell Price` textbox will automatically compute and can also recompute if I change the buyprice onkeyup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like this then,

In HTML:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="sellpCheck" id="scheck" onclick="document.getElementById('sell_price').disabled=this.checked;checkThis();">
```

In JS:

```
function checkThis(){

var buyp = parseInt($('#buyp').val());
var sellp = parseFloat($('#sellp').val());
$('#sell_price').val((buyp * ((sellp/100)+1)).toFixed(2));
}
```

For the change in buyPrice you could use onblur:

In HTML:

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="buy_price" placeholder="Buying Price Per Unit" 
   step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' min="0" max="9999" required id="buyp" onblur="checkThis()">
```

Comment: Only problem on your code was the `elem.checked`. It doesn't disable the `sell_price` text box. I changed it to `this.checked` which worked. Thanks!